# AWS Lambda returning without waiting for promises

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, es6-promise

I have a function working perfectly well within a node environment. The function uses promises, with S3 calls and a then and catch to call the callback with relevant 200/500 statusCode and a message body in each of them.

Now I am deploying it as a lambda function with a wrapper around it looking like this:

```
module.exports.getAvailableDates = (event, context, callback) => {
  const lambdaParams = retrieveParametersFromEvent(event);
  console.log(`Got the criteria`);
  module.exports.getFilteredDates(lambdaParams.startDate,
                                 lambdaParams.endDate, callback);
  console.log(`Returning without the internal function results`);
};
```

The internal function looks like this:

```
module.exports.function getFilteredDates(startDate, endDate) {
  const dateSet = new Set();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const getAllDates = (isDone) => {
      if (isDone) {
        const Dates = Array.from(dateSet).join();
        resolve(Dates);
        return;
      }
      getTestedDates(startDate, endDate, region, func, memory,
        lastDateKey, dateSet).then(getAllDates).catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    };
    lastDateKey = '';
    getTestedDates(startDate, endDate, region, func, memory,
      lastDateKey, dateSet).then(getAllDates).catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

And the even more internal function looks similar, only it actually queries the S3 database and returns the list of keys from it that match the date criteria.

In the AWS CloudWatch logs I see the two prints and only after them the internal function output. My understanding is that the lambda function is not waiting for the internal function with the promises to actually do its work (including the internal waiting on the promises) and returns with a bad status to me. What can I do?

Comment: can u share your `promise` code

Answer (score 0):

Your last `console.log` is executed before the `callback` is executed.

If you want to print the complete statement just before exiting the Lambda, you need to wrap the `callback` ad wait for the Promise to complete:

```
import getFilteredDates from '../path/to/file';

module.exports.getAvailableDates = (event, context, callback) => {
  const lambdaParams = retrieveParametersFromEvent(event);
  console.log(`Got the criteria`);
  getFilteredDates(lambdaParams.startDate,lambdaParams.endDate)
  .then( result => {

    console.log(`Returning the internal function results`);
    return callback();
  })
  .catch(callback);
};
```

I've update the code to work with Promises given the function below.

Your `getFilteredDates` needs to be reshaped a bit:

- Either you to have a third argument to accept the callback inside and handle the Promise chain internally
- Or you expose a promise and handle the callback externally in the main scope.

Let's refactor it to just return a Promise and handle the callback outside:

```
  function getFilteredDates(startDate, endDate) {
    const dateSet = new Set();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const getAllDates = (isDone) => {
        if (isDone) {
          const Dates = Array.from(dateSet).join();
          resolve(Dates);
          return;
        }
        getTestedDates(startDate, endDate, region, func, memory,
          lastDateKey, dateSet).then(getAllDates).catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    };
    lastDateKey = '';
    getTestedDates(startDate, endDate, region, func, memory,
      lastDateKey, dateSet).then(getAllDates).catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
module.exports = getFilteredDates;
```

Comment: I think one of us tot the other one wrong. My problem is not the print, it is that the lambda is returning without waiting for the callback, that is called within my internal getFilteredDates function.

Comment: Hi Marco,
Like before - this works for me in node (locally), but not when deployed as a lambda. Very strange...

Comment: are u using node sdk where promises are not supported ?

Comment: What version of node are you using for Lambda?

Comment: runtime: nodejs6.10

I have a different lambda in that service that _does_ wait for the promise to be fulfilled given the exact same mechanism. I'm pulling my hair to find the differences.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out, it was my bad. The inner function that called the callback with the status code didn't have a `null` when returning 200 (success) and that failed lambda over and over again. Anyway, I rewrote my lambda to be:

```
module.exports.getAvailableDates = (event, context, callback) => {
  const lambdaParams = retrieveParametersFromEvent(event);
  getFilteredDates(lambdaParams.startDate, lambdaParams.endDate)
    .then(Dates => callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: Dates}))
    .catch(error => callback({ statusCode: 500, body: error}));
};
```

And now it works fine. Thanks for anyone who tried helping!

Oren